# How to put a control in the left side of WPF DataGrid Header?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to put a menu in the left side of a WPFDataGrid Header, i dont want to put this menu on each column header using ColumnHeaderStyle ,just one time in the left side.is it possible?how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,Thanks Blend!!

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridControlTemplate1}"/>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <"YourControls"   Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Grid.Column="1">
                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" d:IsLocked="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ScrollViewer.Template>
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and

```
 <DataGridStyle="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}".../>
```